Django -> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
I have installed google-cloud-translate both on my localhost and on my production environment.
pip install google-cloud-translate
When I import it in my Django app with from google.cloud import translate_v2 as translate
then It works fine on my localhost but on my production environment I get this error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'

Although the package is installed in the correct folder:

/home/mysuer/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages

I also created a small test script:
try:
    #import google
    from google.cloud import translate_v2 as translate
    print("Module 'google' found!")
except ImportError as e:
    print("Module 'google' not found:", e)

When I execute this script then the output is: Module 'google' found!
So with the test script the package was found and with my Django app the package was not found!?
Anybody who can help me on this?
I tried debugging, reinstalling the package, checking my Python version, creating a test script, ... but I cannot find a solution...

What is the prod environment ? an server ? a container ?

it looks like  python version problem. how did you verify your test script use the same python version as django? what happens if you replace import statement in production server with full test script code? what does it print out?

@Pycm I checked the python version of the test script and my django app and it's for both the same version.
I just did a test with a view that does the same as my test script. It prints:
Module 'google' not found: No module named 'google'
I really don't understand what is the problem.

Is your project running in a virtual environment? If yes; install the required packages in that virtual environment: see https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html and https://python.land/virtual-environments/virtualenv .
